# Add custom strings around a running process' output

Tags: linux, string, bash, dialog, pipe

I have a "program" which constantly outputs something to STDOUT, when it's running.

I would like to do some changes with the output for Xdialog.

Xdialog uses the STDIN to change it's text in the dialog itself.

In order to do this, I need to wrap any output/text between "XXX\nmydesiredoutput\nXXX\n"

I tried this so far but I can't get my head around it.

At first I create a fifo pipe like so:

```
mkfifo /tmp/mypipe
```

then I can write into that pipe with my desired program

```
myprogram > /tmp/mypipe
```

to open/read the pipe I can use this:

```
(while true ; do cat /tmp/mypipe; done)
```

I am aware that this needs a separate session or background process.

When the reading is "killed", the pipe closes and so does the program.

So technically I can use it like this all togehter:

```
(while true ; do cat /tmp/mypipe; done) | Xdialog --no-close --no-buttons --infobox "$RANDOM" 10 0 0
```

I know how to ADD a certain (suffix/append) string to that output to Xdialog, but I don't know how to add a prefix such as "XXX\n" (echo -e "\n")

Comment: Wouldn't `myprogram | Xdialog ...` be simpler?

Comment: I need to prefix and suffix the output FIRST with "XXX\n"

Comment: Ok, then `myprogram | mutator | Xdialog ...` ?

Comment: Yes. This would work. But which mutator? Also there won't be any EOF meanwhile. So line buffering is neccessary?! Something like with `tee`?

Comment: The mutator would be a program that reads from stdin and writes to stdout. EOF will happen automatically when `myprogram` finishes. I assume that the output from `myprogram` line oriented?

Comment: Yes. The output is line oriented. Also: EOF also happens when the the reading stream is closed, but not relevant

Comment: Well, this is a [tag:bash] question so I'd have to think. In C++ I'd do [this](https://godbolt.org/z/nqEvjazj8). Re: _"EOF also happens when the the reading stream is closed"_ - The mutator should preferably not close the reading stream. If it does, it doesn't need to detect EOF since it _knows_ it's closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put a mutating program in the pipeline between `myprogram` and `Xdialog`:

```
myprogram | mutator | Xdialog ...
```

It could look like this in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# mutator

while IFS= read -r line
do
    printf "XXX\n%s\nXXX\n" "$line"
done
```

---

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -pe 's/.*/XXX\n$&\nXXX/'
```

---

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/.*/XXX\n&\nXXX/'
```

Comment: Mutator could also just be `sed -E s/.*/XXX\n&\nXXX/g`

Comment: @Verpous With that `sed` there is an extra newline at the end so that would be the same as `printf "XXX\n%s\nXXX\n" "$line"`. Getting `sed` to drop that newline without buffering the whole input before doing the substitution seems hard.

Comment: This is it thank you ! Only thing missing is `\n` at the end.

Comment: @Ben Oh, I thought that wasn't supposed to be there according to `XXX\nmydesiredoutput\nXXX` but ok, then Verpous `sed` works just as well. Anyway, you're welcome! Glad it helped!

Comment: @TedLyngmo True. I forgot it in the question and edited it now :) Thank you again for the answer! The `sed` command didn't work unfortunately

Comment: @TedLyngmo Edit: the sed also works. the single quotes were missing.

Comment: @Ben No worries. I updated the answer to match the updated question. The `sed` line  was just lacking single quotes around the regex.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks Ed! I thought `-E` was POSIX compliant for some reason :-) Removed it.